# Textura de la imagen en el pyglet.Player es demasiado azul

Tags: python-3.x

Estaba aprendiendo la biblioteca pyglet y siguiendo los ejemplos que aporta la su documentación, y todo bien hasta que me encontré con este ejercicio de un reproductor de video simple:

```
import pyglet

vidpath = 'Coldplay - Adventure Of A Lifetime (Official Video)-QtXby3twMmI.mp4'

player = pyglet.media.Player()

MediaLoad = pyglet.resource.media(vidpath) # esto es la fuente source

template = pyglet.gl.Config(alpha_sieze=255, stencil_size=0, accum_red_size=0, 
                            accum_green_size=0, accum_blue_size=0,
                            accum_alpha_size=0)
display = pyglet.canvas.get_display()
screen = display.get_default_screen()
config = screen.get_best_config(template)
context = config.create_context(None)

window= pyglet.window.Window(700, 400, caption="Banana split monkey", resizable=True, context=context)

player.queue(MediaLoad)
source = player.source
player.play()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    if player.source and player.source.video_format:
        player.texture.blit(10, 10)

if __name__=='__main__':
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Cuando visionas imagenes -formato png, jpg, gif - y animaciones, . todo bien, salen con la textura correcta, pero cuando utilizo el player, la textura de imagen es muy azulada. He intentado muchas cosas entrando en el pyglet.gl cambiando parámetros o reconfigurando el config del gl, pero nada. A ver si alguiente puede darme una solución a este problema. gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿cómo puedo resolver este problema?

Comment: En este sitio escribe en español, o publica tu pregunta en https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: ok, disculpadme.

Comment: Ok, no hay problema, solo traduce la pregunta, o elimínala de aquí si vas a publicarla en el sitio en inglés.